# error: component download failed for rls-aarch64-apple-darwin: could not download file from

Tags: zsh, rust

I want to using mirror address to speed up the rust package download, so I add the mirror address like this:

```
RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER=https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/rustup rustup install stable
```

but when I execute this command, shows error like this:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin'
warning: Signature verification failed for 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/rustup/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml'
info: latest update on 2022-05-19, rust version 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
info: downloading component 'rls'
error: component download failed for rls-aarch64-apple-darwin: could not download file from 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/rustup/dist/2022-05-19/rls-1.61.0-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.xz' to '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/downloads/49825701cecff4497f1019395880e95d4ae006696d499cba15590a4c37e66c7a.partial'
```

I test the download url from my local machine with google chrome browser and the link works fine. why still got this error? what should I do to fixed this problem? Also tried this:

```
RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER=https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml rustup update
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this command to upgrade the rust in terminal:

```
RUSTUP_DIST_SERVER=https://static.rust-lang.org rustup upgrade
```

when I execute it in macOS 12.4, works.